# Error while installing php-imap on CentOS 6.6

Tags: php, centos6, yum

I'm trying to install php-imap on CentOS 6.6

```
yum install php-imap
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Package: php-common-5.3.29-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-imap-5.3.29-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libc-client.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I try to install `libcurl` by `yum install libcurl` it says it's already installed

```
Package libcurl-7.19.7-40.el6_6.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I can't figure out what's the problem.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 3rd party repository (webtatic), and thats why you are having issues.

What you can do is:

```
yum install php-imap --disablerepo=webtatic
```

This will install php-imap from official CentOS repositories.

Other thing that seems wrong is "w5" in the release version of a package yum is offering you. It suggests that you added Webtatic for EL5 on CentOS 6.x series. From what I can see, webtatic uses "w6" in package release if its meant for EL6/CentOS6.